# validate multiple email addresses with Drupal 8

Tags: forms, validation, email, drupal-8

Currently I am using a renderable array to generate a form which has a HTML 5 email field on it.

Originally the form accepted a single email address.
It needs to be modified to accept a separated list of email addresses AND pass Drupals email field validation.

The current code is

```php
$form['an_email_field'] = [
  '#type' => 'email',
  '#title' => $this->t('enter an email'),
  '#default_value' => 'hello@mail.com',
  '#attributes' =>['multiple']
]
```

The `'#attributes' => ['multiple']` property adds `multiple` to the generated HTML fields attribute list which means HTML 5 will accept the input if multiple email addresses are provided.

But if multiple email addresses are provided Drupal's email validation fails.

Is it possible to make Drupal 8 accept multiple comma separated email addresses when `'#type' => 'email'` is used?

Can this be done without creating a custom validator?

Notes

- I want to ovoid using field types other than email if possible so switching `'#type' => 'email'` to `'#type' => 'textfield'` is not desired unless there is some way to still set the fields type (according the HTML) to email.

Answer (score 1):

With the Webform module installed you could simply use the `webform_email_multiple` element.

```php
$form['an_email_field'] = [
  '#type' => 'webform_email_multiple',
  '#title' => $this->t('enter an email'),
  '#default_value' => 'hello@mail.com',
];
```

Otherwise you may want to use a `textfield` or `textarea` element instead and then do the element or form validation on your own using the `email.validator` service after you exploded the comma-separated string. Here's how the [`validateEmail`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Email.php/function/Email%3A%3AvalidateEmail) function does it on `email` elements:

```php
$value = trim($element['#value']);
$form_state
  ->setValueForElement($element, $value);
if ($value !== '' && !\Drupal::service('email.validator')
  ->isValid($value)) {
  $form_state
    ->setError($element, t('The email address %mail is not valid.', [
    '%mail' => $value,
  ]));
}
```